# Applescript to "tell" Spotify to play isn't working after OSX update to Yosemite

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify

Previously to the Yosemite update, I used [this](https://github.com/dronir/SpotifyControl) Applescript to control my Spotify.

Everything worked as a charm when I ran `/usr/bin/osascript /Users/jdrummond/SpotifyControl.scpt play/pause`.

Now that I have updated my OSX to Yosemite, I keep getting this when I run the same command:

```
/Users/jdrummond/SpotifyControl2.scpt:1217:1222: script error: Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier. (-2741)
```

So I tried to create a simple Applescript to interact with Spotify:

```
using terms from application "Spotify"
    tell application "Spotify" to play
end using terms from
```

But I'm also getting an error:

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong and how to interact with Spotify on Yosemite? Anything changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue was reported to Spotify and will be fixed in the next update to the desktop client (I'm a developer there and can verify that it has been fixed).

Comment: Ok, all I can do is wait now. Thanks.

Comment: This is a temporary fix until the desktop client gets an update:
http://www.unifiedremote.com/tutorials/how-to-get-spotify-version-spotify-101xxx-on-mac-osx

Comment: Are you able to explain how to fix the 'play track' command? After updating the path to sdef most commands work correctly, but not the 'play track' command. It doesn't generate any errors, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Nik, I just updated my Spotify and still can't use Applescript. Are you sure the fix was done in this last update?

Comment: @dmmd yes, I'm very sure about that. :) However, the updated version is still rolling out to end users; it might be another week or two until you get the version with this fix.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the following simple script is working for me on OS X 10.9.5, Spotify 1.0.3.101.gbfa97dfe

```
tell application "Spotify"
    playpause
end tell
```

I saved it as an app in other to use with my Microsoft Keyboard, so that the play/pause button launches the simple app that plays/pauses.

Answer (score 0):

Spotify destroyed the ability to use AppleScript very recently with their latest idiotic update. It's not Yosemite, it's Spotify.

Comment: Do you know any ways I can go back to the older version then?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your answer is correct, as they still have the Applescript "dictionary" on `Spotify/Contents/Resources/applescript/Spotify.sdef`. Any sources you could give me to make sure they really removed integration with Applescript?